# Install Docker on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I checked the documentation page for Docker on Ubuntu and I don't see 18.04, which was released recently.

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Anyone installed docker on 18.04?

**UPDATE**: the docker documentation has been updated now and includes 18.04

Comment: The `bionic` tree is in the docker repo: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/ So the following in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` will work
`deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic edge`

Comment: I have just ran the distribution upgrade to 18.04 putting the above for docker. Docker works out of the box

Comment: @OlegSklyar sorry, not sure I understand your comment. Do you mind if you write in a detailed answer? might be correct so I can accept :)

Comment: You can use `docker.io` with command `sudo apt install docker.io`, as the stable version for bionic hasn't released

Comment: I have enlisted the steps here https://grizzlybit.info/2020-04-11-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18/ give it a shot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following link https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/pool/,
You can choose stable now.

```
$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to install Docker is via Ubuntu image repository:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Restart your computer, then do:

```
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker
```

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-docker/

Answer (score 3):

You can install docker using one simple command:

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

Works not only on ubuntu but on all platforms supported by docker (kinda)

Answer (score 2):

Create an `apt` source-list file with the following content:

> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic nightly
```

Update repositories and install the docker engine:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

You can use `stable` instead of `nightly` in the `deb` declaration of the apt source file as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: At this moment `stable` isn't available. Only `test` and `nightly`, as said by @flv

Comment: Getting the error: - `Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 2):

I followed the installation guide [Get Docker CE for Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

and in step 4 I added the edge repository:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
    $(lsb_release -cs) \
    edge"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, I was not able to install community edition of docker by ading the edge repository (add-apt-repository). Hence, I had to install using the deb files.

In order to install docker community edition on Ubuntu Bionic - I used the following steps.

Step 1: **Download the .deb files using the wget utility**:

```
wget -c https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb
wget -c https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
wget -c https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
```

Step 2: **Now Install the downloaded files using dpkg utility**:

```
sudo dpkg -i containerd.io_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i docker-ce-cli_19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i docker-ce_19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
```

**References:**
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

**Stable Repositories of Docker for Ubuntu Bionic are available at:**
https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/pool/stable/amd64/

Answer (score 0):

18.04 was not a stable release but an `Edge releases`. Switch to the edge channel.

Edit: sorry, you mean Ubuntu 18.04, not Docker 18.04
Maybe this helps: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver

Comment: Stable is also available by now: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/stable/

Comment: @Datz I 've found this post too when I was doing searching on Google, but I'm not sure about this `WARNING: As of now, Bionic is not supported by this repository. Make sure it is at the time you do this. If not, Artful can work as a temporary substitute hence replace the above bionic keyword with artful. Next, you need to add Docker's GPG key. `

Comment: @OlegSklyar it is not - https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/pool/stable/amd64/

Comment: Well, then it will be soon. Take a nightly one for that matter. Conceptually the question was not about using the `stable` release, was it?

Answer (score 0):

You now have three clean options:

- a standard Ubuntu package: docker.io
- a [snap package](https://snapcraft.io/docker) from Docker Inc which has some restrictions on where your Dockerfile is, and is 5 months more out-of-date than the Ubuntu package, but works on more Linux distros
- the official docker-ce package from Docker Inc, which requires their private repo and more install steps

For more helpful instructions, details and references, see [askubuntu: Docker-CE or docker.io package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906289/docker-ce-or-docker-io-package)

Comment: I'm having 18.06.0-ce-dev installed. How can I uninstall it and install the stable version instead? Ihave tried to run `sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io` as per documentation, but I get this `Package 'docker-engine' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'docker' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'docker.io' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: @Lykos How did you originally install it? The answer differs for standard packages (and private apt repo packages) and snap packages.  For snap, to switch channels, see [Basic snap usage | Ubuntu tutorials](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage#4)

Comment: I suggest follow the instructions from Docker documentation now as it has been updated.

Comment: There are advantages to each of the supported methods I describe. The official Docker approach requires more steps, and trusting that their repo is maintained securely, but of course comes straight from Docker, and may get security updates more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can install Docker CE on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic test"
sudo apt update sudo apt install docker-ce
```

Now, check the installed version using this command:

```
docker -v
```